# How do I put python images together using PIL?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am trying to put these cropped sections of PNG images together into one Image file but I am getting and error. Here is my code:

```
panel_one = img_one.crop((0, 0, w, 255))

panel_two = img_two.crop((0, 325, w, 577))

panel_three = img_three.crop((0, 645, w, h))

panel_one.paste(panel_two(0, 255))
panel_one.paste(panel_three(0, 507))
panel_one.show()
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LArSoftDataCompiler.py", line 6, in <module>
    class PI0_Electron_Mixed_2000:
  File "LArSoftDataCompiler.py", line 20, in PI0_Electron_Mixed_2000
    panel_one.paste(panel_two(0, 255))
TypeError: '_ImageCrop' object is not callable
```

How can I put all three panels into one image using PIL?

Comment: What *are* you expecting `panel_two(0, 255)` to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
panel_one.paste(panel_two(0, 255))
panel_one.paste(panel_three(0, 507))
```

Looks like you're missing some commas.

```
panel_one.paste(panel_two, (0, 255))
panel_one.paste(panel_three, (0, 507))
```